# Django Model load choices from a json file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a Django `User` model which contains a `mobile_country_code` field. This field needs to be populated from a list of ISD codes, pre-populated in a json file. What is the best pythonic way to do the same?

My current implementation, which is working:

`json_data/countries.json`

```
[
    ...
    {
        "name": "Malaysia",
        "dial_code": "+60",
        "code": "MY"
    },
    ...
]
```

`project/app/models.py`

```
import json, os

class User(models.Model):
    with open(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/json_data/countries.json') as f:
        countries_json = json.load(f)
        COUNTRIES_ISD_CODES = [(str(country["dial_code"]), str(country["name"])) for country in countries_json]

    mobile_country_code = models.CharField(choices=COUNTRIES_ISD_CODES, help_text="Country ISD code loaded from JSON file")
```

Other Possible options listed below. Which one is better to use?

- Using a model's `__init__` method to create `COUNTRIES_ISD_CODES`
- Importing a library method, like:

  ```
  from library import import_countries_isd_codes

  class User(models.Model):
      mobile_country_code = models.CharField(choices=import_countries_isd_codes())
  ```

Comment: I believe the best approach would be to create a model representing the data and simply imporoit in the database, then just use a `ForeignKey` to choose from

Comment: @Johan I want to keep static values in json files, rather than db. Country codes are never going to change. Also, it is easier to re-use the same json file in Mobile app for user registration flow, where ISD codes are required.

Comment: They're unlikely to change drastically, however they do sometime change (Soviet Union, Czechoslovakia etc). If/when that happens, modifying a JSON-file would break the connection for that choice, rather than having a ForeignKey connected with an ID that would be the same. If you still want to use a JSON file however, I found [this guide](http://blog.rymo.io/2014/04/django-dependent-choicefield-options/) which seems promising for your meet.

Comment: I would just have them as a variable in some `constants.py` file like this one here
https://github.com/shoutit/shoutit-api/blob/a5cea9b764a2e1dcb3a1b8f90b89f8501d743b45/src/common/constants.py#L302

Comment: In similar cases, I prefer to use a .py file where I collect the constants, in order to avoid frequent translations from json to python. Keep in mind that changes to CharField choices need to be tracked in migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Since Django only takes tuples

```
def jsonDjangoTupple(jsonData):
    """
    Django only takes tuples (actual value, human readable name) so we need to repack the json in a dictionay of tuples
    """
    dicOfTupple = dict()
    for key, valueList in jsonData.items():
        dicOfTupple[str(key)]=[(value,value) for value in valueList]
    return dicOfTupple
json_data = jsonDjangoTupple(jsonData)
```

in the model pass something like

```
class User(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=120,choices=json_data['code'])
```

Works for when there's more than one value per key.